# Setting up 2-step / two-factor authentication for LogMeIn

Tags: remote-desktop, logmein

Where can I set up 2-step / two-factor authentication on my account for [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/)? I looked under the security tab but couldn't see anything.

If this is not available on the free plan, which plans is it available on?

The reason I believe they offer it is due to this statement on their site:

> Users also need to authenticate to every LogMeIn host they access remotely. This is done using standard operating system credentials that are never stored on LogMeIn's servers. Users can elect to require the use of a personal password or an RSA SecurID two-factor authenticator when logging in to the host, in addition to supplying operating system credentials.

[Source](https://secure.logmein.com/products/pro/security.aspx).

Comment: Is there a reason you believe LogMeIn offers two-factor authentication at all?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal Please see updated question - i guess they mean the sort of system that Google have setup ie. you get a code texted to you ?

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try any idea how i can move this question or do i need more points to do this ?

Comment: If enough users vote to migrate, it will move automatically. Or you can flag for moderator attention and if they agree that it fits on the destination, they can move it

Answer (score 1):

Once logged into Logmein Central go to users and click on the user you would like to add two factor authentication.  At the bottom under "Extra secutity" there's a Emailed security code feature.  I have this texted to my users when they log in.